# Making elements droppable by using its CSS class Name when multiple CSS classes are applied to a single element

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I've the following element

```
<div class="class1 class2 class3"></div>
```

I'm trying to get all the elements with class name 'class3' using jquery

```
$('.class3').droppable();
```

But i'm not getting the above div as droppable. Any ideas?

Comment: it should work for sure!

Comment: I'm sorry, I posted it wrongly. I have updated the post. I'm not getting it as droppable.

Comment: i have updated the code, check it now. hope thats the answer you are looking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Edit for updated question:*

`.droppable()` doesn't take a function, it takes an object or nothing, you just need this for the defaults:

```
$('.class3').droppable();
```

Also make sure it's in a `document.ready` handler, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('.class3').droppable();
});
```

Then, also make sure jQuery UI is included correctly in your page...you should be getting an error if this isn't the case (`.droppable()` isn't a function, etc).

Comment: @NLV - Updated the answer to match :)

Comment: Thanks! I know droppable() doesn't take a function. Forgot to edit that part :). I've put that inside $(document).ready() but i still dont see it as droppable.

Comment: I dont see ui-droppable class applied to my div element.

Comment: @NLV - You should be getting an error then, if you're not do a `alert($('.class3').length);` in that same `ready` handler to see how many elements it's matching.

Comment: I'm getting 0. Okie i got it. I create the elements dynamically in code behind on user interactions. So document.ready() which is called initially cant find any elements with that class. Will change the logic. Thanks for your help :).

Comment: @NLV - Welcome :) as a tip be sure to include that dynamic part in future questions, will get us on the right track much faster...completely different approach in those cases :)

Comment: Sure. I'm still not getting it. I'll create it as a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

That should work for sure, here are some other potential causes of your error:

**Executed before DOM is ready**
Make sure your code is executed after the DOM has been loaded

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    //Your Code
});
```

**`$` object conflicting**
Several objects make use of the variable `$` as shorthand for their functions, try using `jQuery.` instead.

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
    jQuery('.class3').each(function(){
    });
});
```

**Edit for updated question**
I'm not well versed with the droppable plugin, but the jQuery website has an example which looks like this:

```
$("#droppable").droppable({
  drop: function() { alert('dropped'); }
});
```

More Info: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Droppable

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
    $('.class3').droppable({ accept: 'someselector' });
```

Comment: You should never needs to do this, also `.droppable()` still doesn't take a function.

Comment: thats correct nick, i was taking it as custom function, but thats correct what you are saying.

Comment: There's still no need for a `.each()` here :)

Comment: i have each coz before post was updated it was showing each issue, so i have to reside as soon as i change , post updated as per that. thanks for your input.